# How to mock a singleton class method

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, patch

Suppose we have the following structure:

```
class A():
    class __A():
        def __to_be_mocked(self):
            #something here
    def __init__(self):
        with A.lock:
            if not A.instance:
                A.instance = A.__A()

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return getattr(self.instance,name)
```

Now we want to mock the function `__to_be_mocked`.How can we mock it as the target accepted by `mock.patch.object` is `package.module.ClassName`.I have tried all methods like

```
target = A.__A
target = A.___A
```

and many more.

EDIT:

I solved it using

```
target=A._A__A and attribute as '_A__to_be_mocked`
```

Now the question is `__to_be_mocked` is inside `__A` so shouldn't it be `___A__to_be_mocked` .

Is it because of `setattribute` in `A` or `__init__` in A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mocked a lot of things in python and after did it lot of times I can say:

1. **NEVER** mock/patch `__something` attributes (AKA **private** attributes)
2. **AVOID** to mock/patch `_something` attributes (AKA **protected** attributes)

### Private

If you mock private things you'll tangled production and test code. When you do this kind of mocks there is always a way to obtain the same behavior by patching or mocking public or protected stuffs.

To explain better what I mean by tangling production and test code I can use your example: to patch `A.__B.__to_be_mocked()`  (I replaced `__A` inner class by `__B` to make it more clear) you need to write something like

```
patch('amodule.A._A__B._B__to_be_mocked')
```

Now by patching `__to_be_mocked` you are spreading `A`, `B` and `to_be_mocked` names in your test: that is exactly what I mean to tangled code. So if you need to change some name you should go in all your test and change your patches and no refactoring tool can propose to you to change `_A__B._B` string.

Now if you are a good guy and take your tests clean you can have just a few points where these names come out but if it is a singleton I can bet that it will spot out like mushrooms.

I would like to point out that private and protected have nothing to do with some security concern but are just way to make your code more clear. That point is crystal clear in python where you don't need to be a hacker to change private or protected attributes: these conventions are here just to help you on reading code where you can say *Oh great! I don't need to understand what is it ... it just the dirty work*. IMHO private attributes in python fails this goal (`__` is too long and see it really bother me) and protected are just enough.

Side note: little example to understand python's private naming:

```
>>> class A():
...  class __B():
...   def __c(self):
...    pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> dir(a)
['_A__B', '__doc__', '__module__']
>>> dir(a._A__B)
['_B__c', '__doc__', '__module__']
```

To come back at your case: How your code use `__to_be_mocked()` method? is it possible to have the same effect by patch/mock something else in `A` (and not `A.__A`) class?

Finally, if you are mocking private method to sense something to test you are in the wrong place: never test the *dirty work* it should/may/can change without change your tests. What you need is to test code behavior and not how it is written.

### Protected

If you need test, patch or mock protected stuffs maybe your class hide some collaborators: test it and use your test to refactor your code then clean your tests.

### Disclaimer

Indeed: I spread this kind of crap in my tests and then I fight to remove it when I understand that I can do it better.

Comment: I have already mocked it successfully.... The only understanding left is how did d name mangling work

Comment: I read it now... I stopped to go inside private naming long time ago when I stopped to use private attributes. IMHO they create just noise from Java word and `_` one are enough. I wrote my answer not to cover the technical part but to share my experience about doing this kind of stuffs.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Great answer. I live by this as well. :)  +1

Comment: Can you share why private attributes must not be mocked....any instances or examples?

Comment: @vks I add some explanations. I hope it is enough, but over there I should start to speak about private and protected attributes in python and explain that the target of my tests is primary refatoring.... That means it could be a book chapter and I cannot write about it.

Answer (score 1):

Class & instance members starting with double underscores have their names rewritten to prevent collisions with same-name members in parent classes, making them behave as if "private". So `__B` here is actually accessible as `A._A__B`. (Underscore, class name, double underscored member name). Note that if you use the single-underscore convention (`_B`), no rewriting happens.

That being said, you'll rarely see anyone actually use this form of access and *especially* not in prod code as things are made "private" for a reason. For mocking, maybe, if there's no better way.

Comment: thanx a lot.........i was using `A._A.__B` but is should have been `A._A__B` .Somehow missed it.But now i have another question.Can u please check update

Comment: The rewriting only applies to the property starting with `__`. So no it would be `A._A__A.to_be_mocked`

Comment: the function `to_be_mocked` is actually `__to_be_mocked`.updated question.So my question was regarding that

Comment: Oh I see, you're asking why it's still `_A__to_be_mocked`. Not sure, probably Python just ignores the extra leading underscores for  name mangling purposes.